# Display user name on remote videos on Group chatting, Raise hand feature on Group chatting

Tags: agora.io

We have integrated agora rtc for group video chatting using vue js. Would like to display corresponding user name on remote videos . I am unable pass user name custome property through stream as like userid. How to solve this issue. is there any way to pass custom object to send through stream to remote users.

Raise hand feature also need to do. How to do .

Could you help me

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend using the Agora RTM SDK for your use case. It lets you send messages to other users.

Using RTM whenever you join an RTC channel you can send a channel message to RTM with your name. That way other users can receive and display your name.

For raise hand, you can send a message with a request (eg: {"raise": "true"}), the remote user can then accept/reject the request and send the corresponding message back. If accepted you, you read the message and unmute the local user using RTC method.

You can find a quickstart app for RTM [here](https://github.com/EkaanshArora/Agora-RN-RTM-Quickstart).

Comment: Thank you fetched user information from db for remote user end on user pusblished event.

Comment: @RamaduraiJayaraman Can you please elaborate, how you did this?

Comment: They fetched the username from their own database using the user's UID when the SDK triggers the user-published event.

Comment: This approach is also changing name in currently joined user's name
Can You please share your code that how did you do it?